# "STATUS: Too many open files in system" with open and lock

Tags: c, linux, locking, runtime-error, system-calls

In linux and with C language, I have two function to lock 16 file (MA1, MA2,..., MA16) by 5 process (T1, T2, ..., T5). With acquire(...) a process-i lock the file (if not already locked by a different process), write 0 to 1, and unlock the file. With the release(...) a process lock the file, write 1 to 0, and unlock the file. When I run with a fork() I got the following error from the open `"STATUS: Too many open files in system"`. In linux the maximum is 1024, but I am far to reach that limit with my 5 process

```
alessandro@LinuxAle:~$ ulimit -n
1024
```

the code is:

child exe

```
#include <string.h>
#include "accessory.h"
#include "logfilemanager.h"
#include "lockmanager.h"
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define TRAIN_INITIALS "T"
#define SIZE 256

void next(int step, int *route, int size);

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{

    char *name[2];
    int *route;
    int fdlog;
    char * logprint;

    memset(name, '\0', sizeof(name));
    strcpy(name, TRAIN_INITIALS);
    strcat(name, argv[1]);
    route = get_route(name, "", SIZE);
    print_route(name, route);

    fdlog = create_logfile(name, SIZE);


    for(int i = 1; i < (route[0]+1); i++)
    {
        logprint = update_logfileETC1(fdlog, i, route);
        printf("Train %s: %s", name, logprint);
        fflush(stdout);
        next(i, route, SIZE);
    }
    close(fdlog);
    return 0;
}


void next(int step, int *route, int size) {

    char * next_track_name;
    char * actual_track_name;
    char * next_file_path_name;
    char * actual_file_path_name;
    int status;
    int file_exist;

    /* acquire */
    next_track_name = get_name(route[step+1]);
    next_file_path_name = get_file_name(next_track_name, "", size);
    file_exist = access(next_file_path_name, F_OK); // check if file exist
    if(file_exist == 0)
    {
        status = acquire(next_file_path_name);
        while(status == -1)
        {
            status = acquire(next_file_path_name);
        }
    }

    sleep(3);

    /* release */
    actual_track_name = get_name(route[step]);
    actual_file_path_name = get_file_name(actual_track_name, "", size);
    file_exist = access(actual_file_path_name, F_OK); // check if file exist
    if(file_exist == 0)
    {
        status = release(actual_file_path_name);
        while(status == -1)
        {
            status = release(actual_file_path_name);
        }
    }
}
```

the acquire and release to lock the files

```
include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libgen.h>


int acquire(char *fname)
{

    char c;
    size_t nbytes;
    int status;
    int fd;
    int close_return;
    struct flock lock; //Create an variable of type struct flock to define the properties of locking

    nbytes = sizeof(c);

    fd = open(fname, O_RDWR, (mode_t)777);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        //fd = open(fname, O_RDWR);
        printf("acquire file: %s\n", fname);
        fflush(stdout);
        perror("STATUS");
        exit(1);
    }


    memset(&lock, 0, sizeof(lock));
    lock.l_type = F_WRLCK;
    lock.l_pid = getpid();

    read(fd, &c, nbytes);

    if((c - '0') == 1){
        return -1;
    }

    /* lock the file */
    status = fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &lock);
    if(status == -1)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    lseek(fd, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    read(fd, &c, nbytes);

    if((c - '0') == 0)
    {
        lseek(fd, 0L, SEEK_SET);
        write(fd, "1", nbytes);
    }
    else if ((c - '0') == 1)
    {
        printf("Resource %s is already acquired\n", fname);
        lock.l_type = F_ULOCK;
        if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &lock) == -1 ) {
            perror("fcntl caused some error: ");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    /* Release the lock */
    lock.l_type = F_ULOCK;
    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &lock) == -1 ) {
        perror("fcntl caused some error: ");
        exit(1);
    }

    if((close_return = close(fd)) < 0)
    {
        perror("close");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}



int release(char *fname)
{
    char c;
    size_t nbytes;
    int status;
    int fd;
    int close_return;
    struct flock lock; //Create an variable of type struct flock to define the properties of locking

    nbytes = sizeof(c);

    fd = open(fname, O_RDWR, (mode_t)777);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        //fd = open(fname, O_RDWR);
        printf("release file: %s\n", fname);
        fflush(stdout);
        perror("STATUS");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&lock, 0, sizeof(lock));
    lock.l_type = F_WRLCK;
    lock.l_pid = getpid();

    /* lock the file */
    status = fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &lock);
    if(status == -1)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    lseek(fd, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    write(fd, "0", nbytes);

    /* Release the lock */
    lock.l_type = F_ULOCK;
    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &lock) == -1 ) {
        perror("fcntl caused some error: ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if((close_return = close(fd)) < 0)
    {
        perror("close");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the main with the fork is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include "accessory.h"
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>


#define NUMBER_TRACKS 16
#define NUMBER_STATIONS 8
#define NUMBER_TRAINS 5

#define TRACKS_INITIALS "MA"
#define STATION_INITIALS "S"
#define SIZE 256
#define CHILDETCONE "childETCone"




int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{

    pid_t pid;

    char track_name[2];
    char track_number[2];
    int execl_return;

    char index[2];
    char * execl_path_name;



    /* create the MAx file initialized to zero */
    for(int i = 1; i < (NUMBER_TRACKS+1); i++)
    {
        memset(track_name, '\0', sizeof(track_name));
        memset(track_number, '\0', sizeof(track_number));
        strcpy(track_name, TRACKS_INITIALS);
        sprintf(track_number, "%d", i);
        strcat(track_name, track_number);
        create_track_file(track_name, "", SIZE);
    }

    execl_path_name = get_file_name(CHILDETCONE, "", SIZE);
    printf("path %p\n", execl_path_name);


    for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_TRAINS; i++)
    {
        pid = fork();

        if (pid < 0)
        {
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (pid == 0) //child
        {

            sprintf(index, "%d", i+1);
            execl_return = execl(execl_path_name, CHILDETCONE, index, NULL);
            if(execl_return == -1)
            {
                perror("execl");
                exit(1);
            }
            exit(0);
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_TRAINS; i++)
    {
        wait(NULL);
    }

    return 0;
```

the result is:

```
Route of train T5: [S5, MA4, MA3, MA2, MA1, S1]
Train T5: [Attuale: S5], [Next: MA4], 7 Agosto 2018 0:35:31
Route of train T4: [S6, MA8, MA3, MA2, MA1, S1]
Train T4: [Attuale: S6], [Next: MA8], 7 Agosto 2018 0:35:31
Route of train T3: [S4, MA14, MA15, MA16, MA12, S8]
Train T3: [Attuale: S4], [Next: MA14], 7 Agosto 2018 0:35:31
Route of train T2: [S3, MA9, MA10, MA11, MA12, S8]
Train T2: [Attuale: S3], [Next: MA9], 7 Agosto 2018 0:35:31
Route of train T1: [S2, MA5, MA6, MA7, MA3, MA8, S6]
Train T1: [Attuale: S2], [Next: MA5], 7 Agosto 2018 0:35:31
Train T4: [Attuale: MA8], [Next: MA3], 7 Agosto 2018 0:35:34
Train T5: [Attuale: MA4], [Next: MA3], 7 Agosto 2018 0:35:34
Train T3: [Attuale: MA14], [Next: MA15], 7 Agosto 2018 0:35:34
Train T2: [Attuale: MA9], [Next: MA10], 7 Agosto 2018 0:35:34
Train T1: [Attuale: MA5], [Next: MA6], 7 Agosto 2018 0:35:34
acquire file: /home/alessandro/CLionProjects/ETC1/cmake-build-debug/MA3
STATUS: Too many open files in system
Train T2: [Attuale: MA10], [Next: MA11], 7 Agosto 2018 0:35:37
Train T1: [Attuale: MA6], [Next: MA7], 7 Agosto 2018 0:35:37
Train T4: [Attuale: MA3], [Next: MA2], 7 Agosto 2018 0:35:37
Train T3: [Attuale: MA15], [Next: MA16], 7 Agosto 2018 0:35:37
Train T3: [Attuale: MA16], [Next: MA12], 7 Agosto 2018 0:35:40
Train T4: [Attuale: MA2], [Next: MA1], 7 Agosto 2018 0:35:40
Train T2: [Attuale: MA11], [Next: MA12], 7 Agosto 2018 0:35:40
Train T1: [Attuale: MA7], [Next: MA3], 7 Agosto 2018 0:35:40
acquire file: /home/alessandro/CLionProjects/ETC1/cmake-build-debug/MA12
STATUS: Too many open files in system
Train T3: [Attuale: MA12], [Next: S8], 7 Agosto 2018 0:35:43
Train T4: [Attuale: MA1], [Next: S1], 7 Agosto 2018 0:35:43
Train T1: [Attuale: MA3], [Next: MA8], 7 Agosto 2018 0:35:43
Train T3: [Attuale: S8], [Next: --], 7 Agosto 2018 0:35:46
Train T4: [Attuale: S1], [Next: --], 7 Agosto 2018 0:35:46
Train T1: [Attuale: MA8], [Next: S6], 7 Agosto 2018 0:35:46
Train T1: [Attuale: S6], [Next: --], 7 Agosto 2018 0:35:49

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Your account might have a lower limit. Check `ulimit` to see.

Comment: @Shawn my limit is alessandro@LinuxAle:~$ ulimit -n
1024

Comment: Check, not try to set. What does `ulimit -n` say?

Comment: dear @KamilCuk the parent process create each MAx file (in total 16) initialized to 0

Comment: @Shawn ulimit -n say 1024

Comment: Okay, next question: How often are those `acquire()` and `release()` functions called? They have paths where they can return without closing the file they open. What happens in those cases?

Comment: dear @Shawn for example the process train T1 needs to open (following the order) MA5, MA6, MA7, MA3, MA8. for example  an acquire() is called to lock MA6, write o to 1, unlock. After that sleep(3) and release is called to lock the MA5 file (the previous) write from 1 to 0 and unlock the file.

Comment: This would be so much easier if you posted your complete code so we don't have to play 20 questions.

Comment: Er... that actually compiles? And runs without segfaulting if it does? Wow. I have no idea how. You're not at the very least getting warnings about `strcpy()` and `strcat()` and others? But yes, if those cases that make your `acquire()` and `release()` return without closing the files they open happen, that'll leak descriptors like a sieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `acquire`, you do:

```
if((c - '0') == 1){
    return -1;
}

/* lock the file */
status = fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &lock);
if(status == -1)
{
    return -1;
}
```

If either of these `if` statements return, you will return from the function *without* closing the open file descriptor.

*Note:* Because you didn't post your entire child program code (i.e. the target of the `execle`), it's hard to say what effect this will have for sure, but it is highly suspect.

---

**UPDATE:**

> I diposted the child code

Okay, this clearly confirms the error. Both `acquire` and `release` are called in a *loop* from `next` if *either* one returns -1:

1. This means you will start using up file descriptors on each subsequent call.
2. You're likely to get a [near] infinite loop because `next` will call them again [and again] if it receives a -1 return

Simply add:

```
close(fd);
```

*before* your `return -1` statements above.

Note that `release` also has a similar `if (status == -1) return -1` issue.